# FullCalendar dates and times rendered incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that shows the following full calendar element:

[image]

Below is the json returned by the server in an ajax call for the month of January, 2016:

```
[{"id":17,"title":"39/2015 - Site meeting test 3","start":"\/Date(1451307600000)\/","end":"\/Date(1451316600000)\/","allDay":false,"className":"site-meeting","url":"/OATS/ManageInvestigation/SiteMeetingEvidence/17"},{"id":19,"title":"2/2015 - test","start":"\/Date(1453244400000)\/","end":"\/Date(1453248000000)\/","allDay":false,"className":"site-meeting","url":"/OATS/ManageInvestigation/SiteMeetingEvidence/19"},{"id":20,"title":"2/2015 - test","start":"\/Date(1453345200000)\/","end":"\/Date(1453435200000)\/","allDay":false,"className":"site-meeting","url":"/OATS/ManageInvestigation/SiteMeetingEvidence/20"},{"id":21,"title":"2/2015 - test","start":"\/Date(1453329000000)\/","end":"\/Date(1453505400000)\/","allDay":false,"className":"site-meeting","url":"/OATS/ManageInvestigation/SiteMeetingEvidence/21"},{"id":22,"title":"2/2015 - test","start":"\/Date(1453694400000)\/","end":"\/Date(1453813200000)\/","allDay":false,"className":"site-meeting","url":"/OATS/ManageInvestigation/SiteMeetingEvidence/22"},{"id":23,"title":"2/2015 - test","start":"\/Date(1453935600000)\/","end":"\/Date(1453935600000)\/","allDay":false,"className":"site-meeting","url":"/OATS/ManageInvestigation/SiteMeetingEvidence/23"},{"id":24,"title":"2/2015 - test","start":"\/Date(1452749400000)\/","end":"\/Date(1452823200000)\/","allDay":false,"className":"site-meeting","url":"/OATS/ManageInvestigation/SiteMeetingEvidence/24"},{"id":20,"title":"24/2015 - City Health","start":"\/Date(1452636000000)\/","end":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","allDay":true,"className":"line-correspondence sent","url":"/OATS/ManageInvestigation/ViewLineCorrespondence/20"},{"id":26,"title":"39/2015 - Utility Services","start":"\/Date(1452117600000)\/","end":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","allDay":true,"className":"line-correspondence sent","url":"/OATS/ManageInvestigation/ViewLineCorrespondence/26"},{"id":18,"title":"8/2015 - Journal entry","start":"\/Date(1452549600000)\/","end":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","allDay":true,"className":"journal-entry-reminder","url":"/OATS/ManageInvestigation/ViewCaseJournalEntry/18"}]
```

If I extract the orange event shown on the calendar on 11 January:

```
{
    "id":18,
    "title":"8/2015 - Journal entry",
    "start":"\/Date(1452549600000)\/",
    "end":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/",
    "allDay":true,
    "className":"journal-entry-reminder",
    "url":"/OATS/ManageInvestigation/ViewCaseJournalEntry/18"
}
```

This shows a start date value of: `Date(1452549600000)`. If I use a simple online date/epoch converter, I get the value of:

```
Tue Jan 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
```

Thus, this event should be displayed on the 12th of January, not the 11th.

Also, looking at the times of another event:

[image]

This shows an event that transpires from 5:30AM on 14 January to 2:00AM on 15 January. The json for this event:

```
{
    "id":24,
    "title":"2/2015 - test",
    "start":"\/Date(1452749400000)\/",
    "end":"\/Date(1452823200000)\/",
    "allDay":false,
    "className":"site-meeting",
    "url":"/OATS/ManageInvestigation/SiteMeetingEvidence/24"
}
```

The epoch conversion for these start and end time values respectively:

Start:

```
Thu Jan 14 2016 07:30:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
```

End:

```
Fri Jan 15 2016 04:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
```

On the server I have a simple `CalenderEvent` object:

```
public class CalendarEvent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
    public bool allDay { get; set; }
    public string className { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

That I return to the client as JSON:

```
public JsonResult GetCalendarEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    List<CalendarEvent> events = CalendarEventHelper.GetCalendarEvents(db, CurrentUser.StaffID, start, end);
    return Json(events, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

---

**Edit:**

I just noticed that the second example in the month view does not even show as a 2 day event.

Comment: can you proide fullcalendar configuration regarding timezone?

Comment: @ChintanMirani - You've pointed me in the right direction. I initially set up the timezone to be "Africa/Cairo", but stating this explicitly does not seem to work. I re-looked at the documentation and tried setting the timezone to "local", which seems to have worked. (Even though local should be "Africa/Cairo" as well) - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally I had set the timezone in the configuration of FullCalendar explicitly to "Africa/Cairo". It turns out to not render correctly with this. Setting the timezone to "local", however, does work correctly:

```
$("#Calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    weekNumbers: true,
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: {
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCalendarEvents")',
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        },
    },
    timezone: "local",
    loading: function (bool) {
        $("#Loading").toggle(bool);
    }
});
```

Even though my local machine's timezone is set to Cairo:

[image]

Comment: solves some events but when events start at 00:00 and end 23:59 they do not even appear with "local"